# Android, Get result from third activity

Tags: java, android, listview, android-activity, android-listview

In **first** activity, there is empty `ListView` and `Button`.

When I press button, it starts **second** activity that has `ListView` of categories.

After I click into one of listElements it will start **third** activity that has `ListView` with elements that are belong to my chosen category.

When I choose element of **third** `ListView` it must send me back to **first** activity, where my chosen element is added to my empty `ListView`

Comment: Why don't you use fragments for such use cases?

Comment: On some applications for iPhones, some operations are divided into steps which are switching screens and switches back to first screen to show result.

Comment: Even fragments can be repaced

Answer (score 27):

Use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT` like this:

---

`FirstActivity` should start `SecondActivity` using `startActivityForResult()`.

`SecondActivity` should start `ThirdActivity` using this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ThirdActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

This tells `ThirdActivity` that it should return a result to `FirstActivity`.

`ThirdActivity` should return the result using

```
setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
finish();
```

At that point, `FirstActivity.onActivityResult()` will be called with the data returned from `ThirdActivity`.

Comment: This is working solution

Answer (score 3):

Though I'd implore you to change your architecture design, it is possible to do it like this:

File ActivityOne.java

```
...
startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class), 2);
...
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        //Collect extras from the 'data' object
    }
}
...
```

File ActivityTwo.java

```
...
startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class), 3);
...
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        setResult(resultCode, data);
        finish();
    }
    setResult(RESULT_CANCELLED);
}
...
```

File ActivityThree.java

```
...
//Fill the Intent resultData with the data you need in the first activity
setResult(RESULT_OK, resultData);
finish();
...
```

Comment: Don't do this. It implies noticeable side effects i.e. blinking.